# Help creating a YQL Query to search companies

Tags: sql, yahoo, yql

How can I create a YQL Query that will return me companies from Yahoo Finance?

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where name like "apple"
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that a symbol clause is required, i.e. select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol='appl' and name like "apple". This is useless since you need to have the symbol name already. Is there a way to select all symbols? Everything I tried got rejected by the Yahoo server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work for many reasons. Please try:

```
select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=snl1d1t1ohgdr"
```

To get exactly what you want, you could further filter with xpath in the where clause.

Comment: do you have any tutorials, or documentation on the finance tables? or on the xpath querying for yql?

Comment: There are not many examples around. Here are xpath examples: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html

This is a list of data field abbreviations: http://search.cpan.org/~edd/Finance-YahooQuote/YahooQuote.pm

Answer (score 2):

To get a symbol of any company you can use the below url :

```
http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=<company name>&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

here in the query you can pass any company name that you want the symbol for.

And then to get the stock details about that symbol you can use the below query :

```
select * from csv where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sohgpl1&s=<stock symbol>";
```

here you need to pass the symbol in the comparison with 's'..

So for getting the apple stock information you need to do the following :

```
http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=apple&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

and after getting symbol for apple go for :

```
select * from csv where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sohgpl1&s=AAPL";
```

Hope this will be useful..Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XPATH I would rather recommend to use the build in CSV datatable and to do something like this:

```
select * from csv where url='http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=snl1d1t1ohgdr'
```

The problem with either approach is though that you need to know the stock symbol, so AAPL in this example. So neither my nor the other answer really fulfills your need in terms of being able to search for companies by name.

Don't have more input than this currently, sorry.