# Getting information from Yahoo! finance

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get data about currency exchange from Yahoo! finance in the csv format.

E.g. there is a lot of information in [this page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X), but when I'm downloading csv file over [the url](http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv) there is no such data as Change, Bid, Ask, Prev Close, Open,  etc. There is "N/A" values instead them.

How can I get complete information from relevant page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use Yql. This thread provides an example: [Help creating a YQL Query to search companies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589455/help-creating-a-yql-query-to-search-companies/3589702#3589702)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried to use yql without any success. Query `select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv"` returns same results with "N/A" values

Comment: Ok, try: select * from csv where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv"

Comment: Query `select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv' and columns='symbol,price,date,time,change,col1,high,low,col2'` seems doesn't work too